# Jquery .load() doesn't take value if variable does not have link value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with Jquery `.load()` function it does take value if the passed variable was from `anchor` tag

example (this works)

```
$(function() {
   $(".sel1").change(function() {
      var page = $('.navsubid').attr('href');
      $('.resultoutput').load(page);
    });
});
```

and if a pass values directly to `.load()` it does not load the link

example (not working)

```
$(function() {
   $(".sel1").change(function() {
      $('.resultoutput').load('/somepage');
    });
});
```

`/somepage` is jade page and is rendered in node app.js

any help will be much appreciated. thank you

Comment: How many elements like `<a class="navsubid" href="...` are there on the page?

Comment: Just a single element

Comment: Please include all the relevant HTML.

Comment: @user2881430 How do you know its not working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Do you observe the request/response to the provided url by some network monitoring tool like fiddler?

Comment: The second function is not taking value as href that's why it is not working

Comment: It is taking /somepage as string

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools. @HamletHakobyan is suggesting using fiddler but the browser has the same network inspection built into dev tools also